# Disable overscroll in iOS in ionic 2

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

#### Problem

We have an Ionic2 project. Ionic (on iOS) creates a Safari browser. Safari allows for what I call "overscroll". This is when you can scroll beyond the top or bottom of the page and the page snaps back.

One of our pages has a small signature pad. If a user tries to sign with their finger, they instead scroll the screen. The page content is small enough that it shouldn't be scrollable, but the overscroll causes the page to move.

#### Desired

We just want to disable the blasted overscroll.

Really all of our Ionic projects suffer from this drawback in some form or another, but this is the first project where it blatantly breaks functionality. In other cases it's just an annoyance.

#### Appeal

Is anyone familiar with how to disable this overscroll? Whether through ionic, a cordova plugin,  or the HTML itself.

Answer (score -2):

If I have understood you correctly then this is actually really easy to do.

Just add `no-bounce` to your `<ion-content>` element.

e.g.

```
<ion-content no-bounce>
```

Comment: Just checked this on a project of mine. This works providing that the content of your page fits into one window without scrolling. If it does then no-bounce does the job. If the height of your content exceeds the viewable height then no-bounce seems to have no impact.

Comment: Sorry for belated reply, Chris is correct. This does not work in all cases. We ended up pulling some hoodoo with the header, but was a hack, not a solution.